# Buscar uma palavra ou número dentro do Arquivo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou tentando fazer um sistema que pesquise dentro dos arquivos *txt* de uma pasta através do nome informado na *texbox*, e após localizar arquivos que contenham a informação o sistema deve mover todos para outra pasta.

```
private void TxtMover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String palavra = txtOrigem.Text;    
    string[] lista_ficheiros = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt");

    foreach (string item in lista_ficheiros)
    {
        StreamReader re = File.OpenText(item);    
        string input = re.ReadToEnd();

        if (input.IndexOf(palavra) > 1)
            File.Move(item, @"C:\teste\" + Path.GetFileName(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente qual é o problema?

Comment: Não to conseguindo fazer ele pesquisar a frase dentro dos arquivos e mover todos os arquivos que tenham essa palavra.

Comment: provavelmente não vai conseguir mover um arquivo aberto

Comment: Guarde em uma lista os nome dos arquivos onde você encontrou o texto e realize a operação de `Move` após o término das leituras. Não esqueça da cláusula `using` ou de fazer o dispose de seus readers

Comment: @LeandroAngelo me ajuda plz, to muito perdido :(, comecei a praticar tem muito pouco tempo, oq eu devo acrescentar nesse código que eu fiz pra funcionar?

Comment: Mas qual é exatamente a sua dúvida? o Ricardo já mostrou qual é o erro e eu apresentei algumas soluções... Inclusive acho que só o `using` já pode resolver o seu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado nos comentários, você não consegue mover o arquivo porque ele ainda está sendo utilizado por algum processo. Que no caso é o seu próprio programa, que abriu ele para fazer a busca e não o desalocou. Por isso é importante definir o escopo da operação com o `using` que vai fazer o `Dispose()` do recurso ao término.

Outro ponto de falha na sua lógica é `if (input.IndexOf(palavra) > 1)`, se o arquivo começar com a palavra que você está buscando seu índice será `0` e ele não será detectado. Além disso, você está exposto à falha na detecção por variação de caixa e isso pode ser resolvido com o método `ToLowerInvariant()`

Você também não precisa atribuir valores à variáveis que você vai utilizar apenas uma vez. Principalmente o conteúdo do arquivo, porque você não precisa percorrê-lo ou manipulá-lo posteriormente. Se você não precisa saber a posição da palavra, não é necessário buscar seu índice, apenas saber se ela está presente.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
var textoBusca = "bola";
var origem = @"c:\Temp\arquivos\";
var destino = @"C:\Temp\arquivos\validos\";

foreach (var arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(origem, "*.txt"))
{
    bool contemTexto = false;

    using (StreamReader re = File.OpenText(arquivo))
        contemTexto = re.ReadToEnd().ToLowerInvariant()
                        .Contains(textoBusca.ToLowerInvariant());

    if (contemTexto)
        File.Move(arquivo, destino + Path.GetFileName(arquivo));
}
```

Comment: @Thiago ficou claro?

Comment: Desculpa a demora pra responder, mas tu em ajudou pra K*$#@ ...muito obrigado amigo!